# Changing MFSideMenu options after setup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using the library MFSideMenu and able to set it up correctly. However some pages I want to change some of its options(setting options after setup doesn't seem possible). For example I want to turn off MFSideMenu on a login screen. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your viewDidLoad for your LoginVC:

```
[self.navigationController.sideMenu setPanMode:MFSideMenuPanModeNone];
```

should do the trick.